# Python Tkinter Restart the program without killing it

Tags: python, tkinter, restart

I have one simple question. Is there a way to put some button that will when pressed put everything as it was in moment I started program. Thanks.

Comment: There is such functionality in python/`tkinter`. You will have to program it your self. Just save the state in a file and load it each time the program is opened.

Comment: You mean reset everything to default?